# What are the differences/pros & cons of creating a working copy vs a new branch in git?

Tags: xcode, git, version-control, git-branch

I'm new to coding and Xcode offers both these options. Which one should I take - I just want to manage the changes and easily undo any changes that mess with the app.
Thanks!

Comment: "Working copy" is when you create git repository of current project from scratch. When your project is not under source control. New branch you create, when you already have existing repository.
There are no pros/cons - it is part of git flow.

Comment: Ok, thanks @AlekseyPotapov

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out a description of basic git terminology here: https://www.thomas-krenn.com/en/wiki/Git_Basic_Terms